# What does Jyn mean by, "Trust goes both ways"?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Here is the clip:

What does Jyn mean by, "Trust goes both ways"?

Comment: Nobody wants to hear "You f*cked up - you trusted us!" at the end of the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is being asked to trust, but doesn't feel she is trusted.